# lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit

Tags: luks, lvm, dm-crypt

I get the following error message at boot, just before being asked for my master password to access to my encrypted hard-drive (using dm-encrypt):

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit.
```

I wonder if I did set the whole thing right and how to work around this error at boot.

First, I am running Linux with an unstable (Sid) Debian distribution on a MacBook Pro laptop. So, I am using an UEFI boot (with GRUB2), together with an encrypted hard-drive.

Here are a few information about my setting (feel free to ask more, if you are missing information):

First, here is a reading of my partition (I have a double-boot with MacOS X (also encrypted, so its partitions are not reachable from the Linux part).

```
# df -h
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                      7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     1.6G  9.6M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/Linux-rootfs   55G   24G   30G  45% /
tmpfs                     7.8G  440K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/Linux-homefs  219G   83G  126G  40% /home
/dev/sda4                 922M  253M  606M  30% /boot
/dev/sda1                 197M   28M  170M  14% /boot/efi
cgmfs                     100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                     1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/117
tmpfs                     1.6G   28K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

A few information about my encrypted partition:

```
# cryptsetup status sda5_crypt
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS1
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 512 bits
  device:  /dev/sda5
  offset:  4096 sectors
  size:    582844416 sectors
  mode:    read/write
```

Now, my `/dev/mapper/` content:

```
# ls -al /dev/mapper/ 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     140 Mar 17 09:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root    3360 Mar 17 09:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mar 17 09:49 Linux-homefs -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mar 17 09:49 Linux-rootfs -> ../dm-1
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Mar 17 09:49 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 Mar 17 09:49 sda5_crypt -> ../dm-0
```

And, the `dmsetup table`:

```
# dmsetup table
sda5_crypt: 0 582844416 crypt aes-xts-plain64 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0 8:5 4096
Linux-rootfs: 0 117186560 linear 254:0 2048
Linux-homefs: 0 465649664 linear 254:0 117188608
```

Also, I am compiling my kernel myself, so I might be missing a feature that should be compiled in hard (and not loaded as a module)...

If you have any idea, I would be delighted to understand a bit more about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case after I added a new file with some settings inside usr directory and I got this error during log back in. Then I boot with a live CD and deleted the exact file. worked for me.